# How to target the first use of a template on a page with Hugo?

Tags: hugo

I want to add an ID to the first use of a template on a page with Hugo.

Is there some way of testing for the first use of a template on a page?

E.g. my page has two mailing list sign-up forms, both from my 'subscribe.html' partial. I want to add `id="subscribe"` to the first instance so I can target it with a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and set a flag with `Scratch`, see:

https://gohugo.io/extras/scratch/